# What is the formula to automatically update task progress (% Complete) based on custom flag indicator

Tags: ms-project

In my project I have roughly 45 ongoing tasks that in themselves aren't remarkably important to track progress against and I want to set an automatic rule on these tasks to continuously update progress based on the date. Essentially, these tasks are long duration refining requirements tasks that I don't want to have to constantly manually update to prevent showing on reports.

So far, I have created a custom flag and set those tasks I want to auto run as "yes." Now, I need the appropriate formula to automatically update % complete based on current date for the life of the project.

Does anyone know how the formula needs to be constructed?

Answer (score 0):

You can't update task status (e.g. %complete) using a custom field formula.

The most straightforward way to do what you want is to run the "Update Project" dialog (assuming you're using the desktop client.) I.e.:
 1. Use a filter to show only the tasks with your selection flag set to
    "Yes," then select all of those tasks.
 2. Click "Update Project" on the Status group of the Project ribbon.
 3. Choose a date for "Update work as complete through:" (default will be the Status Date or today if no Status Date is set.)  Then ensure that "Set 0% - 100% complete" is selected.
 4. IMPORTANT: Change the "For:" selection from Entire project to Selected tasks.  Then click OK.

You could automate this with some vba, but the effort is not trivial.